# How to tell what type of battery this is?

Tags: battery, battery-drain, battery-charger, warranty

[image: Picture of top of battery]

I would like to know whether it's either a lead acid wet cell, lead acid gel, or AGM battery.

After reading a bit I see one method is the remove the battery and give it a shake to see if it contains liquid. I'm wondering if there's another way.

I'm curious as my battery charger has a different setting for each of these. Although I'm also wondering how much it matters if I get the wrong setting.

I'm also curious what the "Month 12/60" thing means

Thanks so much and hope this can help others as well

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's one of these:

https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NBP6535

Napa Type 35, 550 CCA wet cell battery

If it was an AGM 35 it would be 640 CCA:

https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NBP983585

-

Not sure on the months thing, possibly an indicator it has a 12 month warranty as standard - NAPA warrant their batteries differently according to the type: http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/content/GenuinePartsCompany/686413pdf?$PDF$

The 60 might be an indicator of extended warranty period if some other additional warranty scheme is purchased. For example, I found [this](https://www.autocareplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ACP-5_50-Warranty.pdf) that mentions warranty periods of 60 months on many components, but this is a complete guess

Comment: Warranties usually work as a replacement within the first period, and a proportional credit for failure within the second period, i.e. if it fails at 3 years out of 5 (60 months) you get 40% back. Seems that's how this one is, but the details are usually printed on the receipt. https://media.napaonline.com/is/content/GenuinePartsCompany/957385pdf